# Api endpoint that edits one element in list

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, put

I am currently building a rest api that lets the user enter a recipe and describe it. I am using spring-boot as backend and angularjs as frontend.

This is springboot recipe file

```
package com.example.springboot;
import com.example.springboot.Recipe;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import  javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class

public class Recipe {

    public Recipe(){

    }

    public Recipe(Integer id, String name, String description, String type, Integer preptime, Integer cooktime, String content, Integer difficulty){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.preptime = preptimee;
        this.cooktime = cooktime;
        this.content = content;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;


    private String name;


    private String description;


    private String type;


    private Integer preptime;




    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String content;

    private Integer difficulty;






    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Integer getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

    public void setDifficulty(Integer difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }



    public Integer getpreptime {
        return preptime;
    }

    public void setpreptime(Integer preptime) {
        this.preptime = preptime;
    }
}
```

I created an Endpoint where the user can edit the whole recipe. The user can edit the name , description, content and so on in the recipes/edit/{id} endpoint.
The Endpoint looks like this.

```
@PutMapping("/recipes/edit/{id}")
    void updateRecipe(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody Recipe recipe ) {
        System.out.println("entering");
        Recipe recipe_ = recipeRepository.findById(id).get();
        recipe_.setName(recipe.getName());
        recipe_.setDescription(recipe.getDescription());
        recipe_.setType(recipe.getType());
        recipe_.setpreptime(recipe.getpreptime());
        recipe_.setContent(recipe.getContent());


        System.out.println("entering " + recipe.getTitle());
        System.out.println("entering" + recipe.getType());
        System.out.println("entering" + recipe.getDescription());


        System.out.println("adding");
        recipeRepository.save(recipe_);
    }
```

Now I just want to create an Endpoint which only serves the purpose for renaming the name of the recipe. This putmapping should accept a list as its input then only rename the name of the recipe.

```
   @PutMapping("/recipes/rename")
      public List<Recipe> {
       System.out.println("entering renaming");
     //  recipe_.setName(recipe.getName()); ?


}
```

I don't know how I can implement this. This is what I have come up with so far. An endpoint which takes a list as a parameter.

This is the service.ts file that updates the Recipes in the edit function
service.ts:

```
updateRecipe (id: number, recipe: any): Observable<any > {
    const url = `${this.usersUrl}/edit/${id}`;
  return this.http.put(url ,recipe);
}
```

where the updateRecipe gets called:

```
 save(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');
     this.recipeService.updateRecipe2(id, this.recipes)
       .subscribe(() => this.gotoUserList());

   }
```

This implementation work , I don't know how I can get it work or how I can rewrite the functions so that it can update only the name of the recipe and not the whole file.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Do you want both methods: 1 updates only name of recipe, other updates whole object?

Comment: @andrew17 only updates the name of the recipe

Comment: But why you want accept list of recipes while renaming only one object?

Comment: @andrew17 I was thinking I need to accept the list of recipes and edit them in one go. Or is there a simpler approach ?

Comment: Do you want to update the name of one recipe? or you want to set one name to many recipes?

Answer (score 0):

Your `update the name` method should look like that:

```
@PutMapping("...{id}")
public void updateName(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestParam String name){
    Recipe recipe = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(...);
    recipe.setName(name);
}
```

if you want to rename list of recipes

```
public void renameRecipes(String oldName, String newName){
    repository.findByName(oldName)
              .forEach(r -> r.setName(newName));
}

@PutMapping("recipes/rename")
public void updateNames(@PequestParam String oldName, @RequestParam String newName){
    renameRecipes(oldName, newName);
}
```

Try that.

Comment: when I send a json object through postman that looks like this  `{
 "name": "sushi",
 
  }` I get required string parameter 'name' is not present

Comment: this is when I use your first example

Comment: you dont need JSON object,request looks like .../12?name=sushi

Comment: Im guessing that 12 is for example the id number. Even if send the request it doesn't change the name in the database

Comment: then you are doing something wrong, the code must work. show the full controller and service methods

Comment: with service methods do you mean the spring boot recipe file I added above?

Comment: spring boot recipe file? I dont know that termin

Comment: I mean the code after 'This is springboot recipe file'

Comment: I think you are not ready to use Spring and Jpa/Hibernate. I suggest you to start read books about spring and hibernate seperatly. Better to start from Hibernate.
About code, do you have repository for Recipe entity? How did you persist data to your database for updating that after? Notice, that JPA has no ready `update` method for usage. You have to implement it in some way you need.

Comment: this is how my repository looks for the recipe entity package com.example.springboot;
`import com.example.springboot.Recipe;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


// This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
// CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

public interface RecipeRepository extends CrudRepository<Recipe, Integer> {

}`

Comment: dont add code to the comment. Add it to your question:) Okey, if you find by id your entity in database and set new data - it should be updated. You do something wrong

Comment: could you give me a hint where the mistake could be?

Comment: @momonosuke Create entity -> create repository -> create service method 'rename' with findById implementation of repository method and there set new name of recipe -> create controller method that requests that business logic.